# How to enable different languages to input in android

Tags: android

I can't input russian symbols in AutoCompleteTextView, when run my application in DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your asking for but if you want to support multiple languages, You can use alternative resources for the different locales you plan to target.

See:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

If you want to change the language in your emulator, do this:

Open menu=>Setting=>Language& Keyboard=>Select Locale=>set any locale from this

Comment: When I run my application in DDMS, I can't input russian symbols in edittext, only english